# How to Compare strings of 1 column with strings of another within the same dataframe, calculate the percentage of strings matching in result columns

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, fuzzywuzzy, difflib

How to Compare strings of 1 column with strings of another within the same dataframe, calculate the percentage of strings matching in result columns, as well as whether they are full matches, partial matches, or don't match at all?

[image]

Comment: How do you compute the percentage for two words?

Comment: What have you tried so far? and whats the result of it?

Comment: @Naveed I am using fuzzy logic for the same but not able to write the code.Thats why I need  help.

Comment: @richardec write now I am working on critical data and I need to match customer name of 2 columns so that i can proceed, so I just thought about this logic and I am also not sure its right or not, so I am just asking can I achieve this or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```py
import pandas as pd
table = {
    'Column_01':['Apple', 'Mango', 'Banana','Coconut','Pineaple','Guava'],
    'Column_02':['Apple','Man','Fruits','Cocon','Pin','Guava']
           }
tf1 = pd.DataFrame(table)


print(tf1)

print(f'\n\n-------------BREAK-----------\n\n')


def func(x):
    len_col1 = len(x[0])
    cont = 0
    for y in range (0, len_col1):
        try:
            if x[0][y] == x[1][y]:
                cont += 1
            else:
                pass
        except:
            break
    return round(((cont* 100)/len_col1),2)

def func2(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 'Not match at all'
    elif x < 100:
        return 'Partial match'
    else:
        return 'Full match'

tf1['% of Matching Stings'] = tf1.apply(func, axis = 1) 

tf1['Status'] = tf1['% of Matching Stings'].apply(func2)

print(tf1)
```

OUTPUT

```py
  Column_01 Column_02
0     Apple     Apple
1     Mango       Man
2    Banana    Fruits
3   Coconut     Cocon
4  Pineaple       Pin
5     Guava     Guava


-------------BREAK-----------


  Column_01 Column_02  % of Matching Stings            Status
0     Apple     Apple                100.00        Full match
1     Mango       Man                 60.00     Partial match
2    Banana    Fruits                  0.00  Not match at all
3   Coconut     Cocon                 71.43     Partial match
4  Pineaple       Pin                 37.50     Partial match
5     Guava     Guava                100.00        Full match
```

Comment: rafael-m-r-de-rezende Thank you so much for your help .........

Comment: I ask you to rate this issue as resolved, on the button next to my answer there is an OK button, if you can rate it, I appreciate it